# Same sculpting curve on multiple brushes?

Tags: bezier-curves, sculpting, brushes

I've looked around the internet, but couldn't find anything about this..

Is there any way to use the same sculpting curve for multiple brushes?
I'd like to first *draw sharp* along a curve to make a crevice, and then *pinch* along the same curve to tighten it up.

Any pointers?

Thanks and happy blendering!